# x-show with local storage value don't work

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have the element with `x-show="localStorage.getItem('hi') == 'hi'"`. When I change value like `localStorage.setItem('hi', 'hello')`, The element should be hidden, but it doesn't hide. How can I make the element hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is not updated, so it works like `x-show="undefined == 'hi'"`. you can detect localStorage updates (or put a function every time you update it) and update x-show.